# Remove Observers Before Initialization in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I have a TableView with Cells obtaining/losing an observer depending on whether the cell is loaded on the view or not. I have a side menu that appears when the user swipes to the right and the options in the menu initializes a new view and presents it. As a result, there are some observers still active and that throws errors.

The first error I received was

> An instance of class MM.ActivityCell was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.

I figured this was a simple fix; I just had to remove the observers when the cells were deallocated. However, I forgot to account for the fact that the deallocation occurs for cells that may not necessarily have the observers.

The error, doing what I did, becomes:

> reason: 'Cannot remove an observer ... for the key path "frame" from ... because it is not registered as an observer.'

I understand the fact that I cannot remove observers that do not exist, and that I must deallocate each observer before doing what I want to do. I've also thought of using `viewWillDisappear` or a try catch block. Using viewWillDisappear was my first thought but I cannot imagine a simple way of managing the list of cells that are being displayed and accessing them. So I turned to the Try Catch Block.

Within ActivityCell,

> ```
>   do {
>         try removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
>     } catch NSRangeException {
>         println("RIP")
>     }
> ```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is the purpose of the observer on the cell?

Comment: I have it because I want the cell to "expand" when tapped to allow the user to edit information.

Comment: Instead of observers, implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in your view controller. This will get called when a cell is tapped and you can then do what you want with that cell.

Comment: That actually sounds like a better idea. Thanks.